# If $\frac{d}{c} > \frac{b}{a} +1$, is $a \ln(b+1)+c \ln(d-1)-a\ln(b)-c\ln(d)>0$?

Tags: inequality, logarithms

If $\dfrac{d}{c}>\dfrac{b}{a} +1$, is it true that
$$a \ln(b+1)+c \ln(d-1)-a\ln(b)-c\ln(d)>0?$$

where $a, b, c, d$ are integers, and $a, c \geq 1$, and $b, d \geq 2$.

It seems to be that it might be true (I've not been successful at finding a counterexample so far), but I've tried proving using the product and quotient rules, though to no avail.

Comment: It's not true: try $a=0.3,b=0.4,c=0.5,d=1.2$. Perhaps you want $a,b,c,d>1$.

Comment: @Toby Mak Ah right, forgot to add that $a, b, c, d$ are integers, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

$$a \ln(b+1)+c \ln(d-1)-a\ln(b)-c\ln(d)=\ln \left(\left(1+\frac{1}{b} \right)^a \left(1-\frac{1}{d} \right)^{c} \right)$$

Then use the given inequality
$\frac{c}{d}<\frac{a}{a+b}<\frac{a}{b}$

I think you can take it from here

Comment: Yea I got that as well.. but $\left( 1-\frac{1}{d} \right) < 1$ -- How would that term relate to the condition given? Sorry if I'm not seeing something obvious!

Comment: That's where the inequality comes into play,$\frac{c}{d} <\frac{a}{a+b} <\frac{a}{b}$, I see, I'd not added that

Comment: I've been at it for days but can seem to make any progress on this, do you have another clue that I can work with? (a theorem perhaps?) Thanks!

Comment: Try using Bernoulli's inequality

Comment: Ah i see.. thanks! :)